# Which is preferable for comparison with each other - List<int> or int[]?

Tags: c#, arrays, list, int

I need to compare an original value from a collection of controls (the Text value, converted to ints of 0..3, to be specific) with the updated values.

Which is more suitable (*List* or *int[]*) for such comparisons?

I'll need to compare each element with its "companion" element in the other list or array.

Comment: Suitable in which sense? Can you give an example of comparison?

Comment: Something along the lines of: if (original[i] == changed[i])

Comment: Then they are both a good solution, since arrays (and Lists, as I've said in my answer) are very fast at iterating linearly or jumping to random positions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Internally `List` also uses an array (a dynamically resizing array that is), so as far as operations go, they are the same.

Comment: What do you mean by dynamic array? `List<T>` uses `T[]` internally, but there's nothing dynamic about it ...

Comment: @BrianRasmussen I guess it's dynamic in that it's not a single array, `List` is regularly creating new arrays.  I agree, it does sound odd though.

Comment: Dynamic in the sense that it adjusts its allocated space according to adds/deletes, since it cannot know beforehand how many items you intend to add. MSDN: `It implements the IList<T> generic interface using an array whose size is dynamically increased as required.`

Comment: @Tudor: I'm aware of how `List<T>` is implemented, and I would say that it handles sizing dynamically, but I wouldn't call the array itself dynamic. Every time the current capacity is exhausted a new array is created and the data copied from the old to the new. The array is just a regular array. All the dynamic stuff is handled by `List<T>`.

Comment: @Brian Rasmussen: Then sorry, it was a bad wording on my part. I'll correct it.

Comment: @Tudor: No problem. I just found your choice of words a little confusing. Thanks for updating.

Answer (score 1):

Any `IEnumerable<int>` should be fine.

```
var pre = Enumerable.Range(1, 3);
var post = new [] {0, 2, 1};

var same = pre.Zip(post, (before, after) => new {before, after})
    .Where(x => x.before == x.after);

Assert.AreEqual(1, same.Count());
```